# Python Polars - Finding min value greater than col(a) in col(b) where col(a) is a numeric and col(b) is a column of lists of numerics

Tags: python-polars

How do I convert the following slow operation in pandas to a fast operation in polars?

`df.to_pandas().apply(lambda x: pd.cut([x['ingame_timestamp']], list(x['time_bins']), list(x['time_bins'])[1:]), axis=1)`

Assume ingame_timestamp is a float and time_bins is a list.

I basically want to be able to do something like:

```
df.with_columns(pl.cut(value=pl.col('val'), bins=pl.col('time_bins), labels=pl.col('time_bins')[1:]).alias('val_time_bin'))
```

The above code works when I use to_pandas() but obviously this loses a bunch of the speed benefits of using polars and not using apply.

The following gives you an example data frame along with a column which is the desired output:

```
example_df = pl.DataFrame({'values': [0,1,2], 'time_bins': [[-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1], [0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [1.5, 2.5, 3, 4.5]], 'value_time_bin': [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]})
```

It is sufficient to find the minimum value greater than "value" in the list "time_bins".

Comment: Can you provide example of dataframe?

Comment: You can't use `pl.cut` inside `df.with_columns` ([see doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.cut.html#polars.cut)) because `df.with_columns` takes *Expressions* as argument but `pl.cut` returns *DataFrame*.

Comment: Added an example, understood about cut!

Comment: can you add a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# reproducible dataset
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'values': [0, 1, 2],
    'time_bins': [[-1., -0.5, 0.5, 1.], [0., 0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [1.5, 2.5, 3, 4.5]]
})
```

If I understood you right, you need to create column with min value from `time_bins` that is greater than value in `values`.

One way to do it:

```py
df.explode("time_bins").groupby("values").agg([
    pl.col("time_bins").list(),
    pl.col("time_bins").filter(
        pl.col("time_bins") > pl.col("values")
    ).min().alias("value_time_bin")
])
```

```
┌────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ values ┆ time_bins             ┆ value_time_bin │
│ ---    ┆ ---                   ┆ ---            │
│ i64    ┆ list[f64]             ┆ f32            │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [-1.0, -0.5, ... 1.0] ┆ 0.5            │
│ 1      ┆ [0.0, 0.5, ... 2.5]   ┆ 1.5            │
│ 2      ┆ [1.5, 2.5, ... 4.5]   ┆ 2.5            │
└────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is great, I really need to get used to exploding dfs more! I will update the question to better reflect what is being asked for future reference.